# sed & awk, second column modifications

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I've got a file that I need to make some simple modifications to. Normally, I wouldn't have an issue, however the columns are nearly identical which throws me off.

Some examples:

```
net_192.168.0.64_26 192.168.0.64_26  
net_192.168.0.128-26 192.168.0.128-26
```

etc

Now, normally in a stream I'd just modify the second column, however I need to write this to a file which confuses me.

The following string does what I need it do to but then I lose visibility to the first column, and can't pipe it somewhere useful:

```
cat file.txt | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/1_//g;s/2_//g;s/1-//g;s/2-//g;s/_/\ /g;s/-/\ /g' | egrep '[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}'
```

Output needs to look like (subnet becomes the 3rd column):

```
net_192.168.0.64_26 192.168.0.64 26  
net_192.168.0.128-26 192.168.0.128 26
```

How do I do what the above line does, while keeping both columns visible so I can pipe them to a new file/modify the old etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to replace the characters `_`,`-` with a single space from the second field then:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/[-_]/," ",$2)}1' file
net_192.168.0.64_26 192.168.0.64 26
net_192.168.0.128-26 192.168.0.128 26
```

Comment: Well, you answered first, I guess this goes to you :)
thank you sir!

Answer (score 2):

try this, if it is ok for you:

```
awk '{gsub(/[_-]/," ",$2)}1' file
```

test with your example text:

```
kent$  echo "net_192.168.0.64_26 192.168.0.64_26  
net_192.168.0.128-26 192.168.0.128-26"|awk '{gsub(/[_-]/," ",$2)}1'
net_192.168.0.64_26 192.168.0.64 26
net_192.168.0.128-26 192.168.0.128 26
```

Answer (score 1):

And a `sed` version:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)[-_]/\1 /' file
```